# VC++: std::endl has strange execution time

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, std

I recently noticed strange behavior in Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition. The output speed of the following VC++ code (made in an "empty project"), when run in or out of VS dramatically increases in speed when the execution reaches the 2nd while loop.

Curious, I ran some benchmarks using `std::chrono::system_clock::now()`. The execution time of the first while loop took over 7 seconds; The execution time of the second while loop took under 3.

I then ran some more tests, and noticed the strange behavior vanished when I removed both of the `std::endl` s; They both executed in ~1.5-2 seconds.

What is causing this behavior?

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int i = 0;
    while (i <= 9999) { 
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
        i++;
    }

    while (i <= 19999) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
        i++;
    }
}
```

EDIT: I should have clarified I'm using a release build.

Comment: [`std::endl`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) doesn't only print a newline, it does more. I really recommend *not* using it unless you need to use *all* of its features. If you want to print a newline, print a newline `'\n'`.

Comment: *made in an "empty project")* -- Are you timing a "debug" build or "release"/optimized build?  If timing a debug build, the times you're showing are basically meaningless, and instead you need to time release/optimized builds.

Comment: The overall reduction in execution time after removing `std::endl` is very obvious. `std::endl` executes a flush, which is expensive. Not flushing `std::out` resutls in much larger output buffers being used, so that's that. As far as disparity in relative execution times, this sounds like the CPU's branch predictor kicking in.

Comment: I assume you are timing an optimized release build and *not* a debug build. If not, do that now. Benchmarking debug builds is pointless.

Comment: Hmm, printing 10000 numbers takes 2 seconds? Even a C64 is faster than that.

Comment: I was wondering why `endl` (or, rather, `cout` with `endl`) exhibited changes, depending on the value of `i`. And sorry, I should have made it clear I was using a release build.

Comment: It won't be related to the value of `i`.   It will be waited to workings of stream buffering and how flushing works (e.g. how contents of buffers of different lengths are actually output, whether the buffer is cleared, whether the buffer is dynamically resized, etc)